# How to add validation to knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have a field in the class:

```
self.address = ko.observable().extend({
    required: true,
    maxLength: {
        params: 1000,
        message: 'Long address'
    },
    validation: {
        validator: function(val, substring) {
            return /*...*/;
        },
        message: 'Address not found',
        params: ''
    }
});
```

HTML fragment:

```
<div class="form-additem-group-row__col form-additem-group-row__col_field">
    <input type="text" id="addressInput" class="field field_type2 input--full" placeholder="Enter the address" data-bind="textInput: address, geoModuleInput: { mapObject: map, debugSuggestCont: '#currentSuggest', valueText: address, valueKey: addressKey, valueMetroName: metroName, valueMetroDuration: metroDuration, valueGeoCodeResult: geoCodeResult }"/>
    <div class="form-additem-group-row__error" data-bind="validationMessage: address"></div>
</div>
```

Address processing takes place in the module `geoModuleInput` and whether an address exists or not.

How to call validation if the address does not exist?

Comment: could you show the rest of the code? including geoModuleInput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `valueAccessor` parameter in your custom binding to access whatever was passed to the binding, including the observable `address`.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.geoModuleInput = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // if you have any custom binding initialization
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // valueAccessor() has the object that was passed
        // it has properties like "mapObject", "valueText" etc
        // or you can also use ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var bindingData = valueAccessor();

        console.log(bindingData.valueText()) // gives the value in address observable

        if(bindingData.valueText.isValid()) {
            alert("the address is valid");
        }
    }
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/jvgrxkjh/7/) for testing it out.